# Rails - Show all models that belongs_to this User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-associations

If I have a `User` that `has_many :problems`, assuming I have set up the necessary association between `User` and `Problem` , how can I do something like:

```
  # UsersController.rb
  def students_problems
     @userId = params[:user_id]
     @problems = give me all problems associated with this @userId
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])

@problems = @user.problems
```

Ideally you would want to do this in a model if you plan to do more with your code. So you can create a model method like this for your controller.

```
@problems = User.name_your_method_here(params[:user_id])
```

Then in your User model you have

```
self.name_your_method_here(user_id)
  User.find(user_id).problems
end
```

And you might want to add some conditionals to make sure the `user_id` matches a real user but I'll leave that up to you to do.

EDIT: As lebreeze suggests, it might be wise to change the name of the method to something different, at least to what it relates with what you're doing with your code.

Comment: I would not recommend using instance variables in your model method as their scope will leak. Also implementing a `find_problems` method, in this instance, adds unnecessary bloat to the methods already provided by ActiveRecord.

Comment: Ahh good call. I'll adjust the code. By point was to show what was possible with model methods. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Thanks to both for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all your associations and db fields are correct.

```
@problems = User.find(params[:user_id]).problems
```